# Is there a workaround for running multiple instances of a class with static variables in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, static

I'm working on an existing piece of simulator software, and the structure is basically like this (it has a static member variable containing itself):

```
public class Simulator {
    private Static Simulator instance;

    public Simulator(){
        instance = this;
        //blah
        //blah
        //other things
    }

}
```

And then a lot of methods access the static instance of the Simulator like this:

```
for(Foo f : Simulator.instance.getFoo() ){
    //blah
}
```

You get this idea. Basically, the programmers who came before me assumed that there would only ever be one single instance of the Simualtor, so they made it accessible statically.

The problem is that I now want to run multiple instances of it, so this static part is becoming annoying.

Making this work without it being static is probably the best option, I know, but as you can imagine it will take a lot of refactoring and time.

The one thing that does work is to run multiple main methods (so run it several times in my IDE, or run it as a .jar in separate windows). I assume this is because each main method or JVM instance or whatever is acting as a sort of container, so the statics don't interfere?

What I was wondering was, is there a hacky workaround that I can use (at least short-term) to create multiple instances of the simulator, but within some kind of container that makes the static instances not interfere.

Comment: You don't want a hacky workaround. Just make it non-static. A bit more work now (not that much if you have a good IDE) but it'll save you a lot of headaches in the long term

Comment: To be honest, your question is kind of excessive in its text. I, personally, find it a bit difficult to understand what you exactly are trying to do, and what's the problem. Could you narrow down it to the specific point you're struggling with?

Comment: Basically I was hoping for a quick short-term solution to the problem of the static not being different for different instances. I was hoping that I could emulate that way that running multiple main methods at the same time allows each instance to be containerised I guess.

Comment: @W.Hunt static member will NOT be different for different instances, unless you explicitly reassign it.

Comment: You might be able to do it by loading the class through multiple classloaders, though I'm not 100% sure that would be a viable route. Fixing the actual problem might be easier than attempting to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is possible using Java class loaders ([ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)), but this will lead you into a world of pain. You would have to create sub-applications each using different class loaders. I have never done this, but I believe this is how application servers work.

It will be far easier to refactor your application.

Instead of accessing `instance` you would have to create multiple instance variables or some dynamic registry like a map where you store the references.

By-the-way, the way that `instance` is stored in the constructor is very bad practice as it will get overwritten each time `new` is called and the previous version will be lost. Usually, you would want to just initialise `instance` with an object.

Comment: +1: this is certainly *possible*, but as you hinted at, it's not clear that doing this correctly is actually easier and less painful than refactoring the code.

Comment: OK great. I think I will probably refactor it in the end, but great to know there is a workaround. This is intended to work as an application server in the end, and so that could be a good option. Cheers all

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and hacky way that I could think of is to override that constructor with a dummy variable

```
    public Simulator(Boolean isDummy){

    }
```

Now you have the option to create a multiple instance of that class without affecting others. Not sure if the parameter overhead is acceptable in your case.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice idea, but I ideally need to retain functionality of each of my multiple instances of the Simulator object, and so would in theory need the "instance" variable to still work (i.e. refer to this instance of the class) for each instance of the simulator class.